# Error en consulta Firestore al cerrar sesión

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-auth

tengo actualmente inconveniente con  mi consulta Firebase Firestore despues de cerrar la sesión, pasa que cuando cierro sesión hago una recarga a la activity (Estoy trabajando con Fragments en Android Studio) al llegar la misma me sale el Toast que he puesto para cuando hay un error en la consulta, sin embargo al cerrar la aplicación y volver a abrir sin una sesión activa, carga de manera normal...

Este código es el que estoy usando para cerrar la sesión desde el Activity

```
FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
MenuItem itemCloseSession = binding.navView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_SigOut);

itemCloseSession.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                mAuth.signOut();
                finish();
                overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                startActivity(getIntent());
                overridePendingTransition(0,0);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Este es el código que tengo **En el Fragment** para realizar la consulta y llenar el ArrayList que funcionará con el adaptador para luego mostrar los datos en un recycler view dentro del fragment.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();
        return root;
    }

@Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        ArrayList<Product> productArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        ProductAdapter productAdapter = new ProductAdapter(getActivity(), getContext(), productArrayList, firestore);
        binding.rvListProducts.setHasFixedSize(true);
        binding.rvListProducts.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        binding.rvListProducts.setAdapter(productAdapter);
        
        getProducts();

}

public void getProducts(){
        firestore.collection("products")
                .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                        if(error != null){
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Failed to retrieve data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return;
                        }
                        for (DocumentChange dc : value.getDocumentChanges()){
                            if(dc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){
                                productArrayList.add(dc.getDocument().toObject(Product.class));
                            }
                            productAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Estoy comenzando en esto de la programación y aunque sé que hay miles de formas de realizar lo que ahí estoy haciendo quisiera saber cual es la forma mas indicada para hacer ese proceso y que no me salte error al cerrar la sesión y recargar la activity.

En contexto, he visto ejemplos donde tienen el Login en una activity diferente, por ende al cerrar sesión van a la activity del login y pues ponen el parametro de seguridad para que no se pueda regresar al activity anterior sin antes iniciar sesion... En mi caso, solo tengo 1 activity y con ella tengo todos los demas fragments de mi aplicación, estoy usando Navigation Drawer para la navegación, lo que quisiera lograr es cerrar la sesion sin irme a otra activity, es por ello que intento hacer un `finish()` a la activity actual y vuelvo a cargar la misma, pero es ahi donde me salta el error en la consulta de los productos a firebase.

Desde ya gracias por sus comentarios estoy al pendiente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado el error, a continuación dejo mi respuesta para claridad de las personas que quizás les pueda servir...

En mi caso particular pasó que al momento de crear la base de datos en el Firebase Firestore, en las reglas de lectura y escritura había declarado la siguiente línea de código.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Esto lo que me permitía es **LEER** o realizar cambios en la base de datos siempre y cuando hubiese una sesión de usuario activa, honestamente había olvidado esta configuración, llegué a notarla cuando convertí el error a una cadena de texto para mostrarlo en un Toast, la consulta me arrojaba un error, entonces hice

```
if(error != null){
 Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), 
 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 return;
}
```

Cambie mi texto que en realidad no me mostraba el error por el mensaje que me estaba arrojando Firebase, noté que era un tema de permisos, al cerrar la sesión, automáticamente quedaba sin permisos para leer en la base de datos, para ello, entonces usé un condicional de tiempo directamente en Firestore...

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2021, 12, 31);
    }
  }
}
```

Especificando una fecha que podría tener la aplicación en desarrollo y usar la base de datos como prueba.

Realicé las pruebas y ahora la aplicación funciona sin inconvenientes.